# Maestro UI test run after this error printing?

Tags: java, kotlin, ui-automation, maestro

I am UI tesrting with maestro UI test automation tools for flutter app, but after running a test this error occurred:

```
i@is-MacBook-Pro samples % maestro test android-flow.yaml 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.io.InputStream.readAllBytes()[B
    at maestro.cli.device.ios.Simctl.list(Simctl.kt:14)
    at maestro.cli.device.DeviceService.listIOSDevices(DeviceService.kt:164)
    at maestro.cli.device.DeviceService.listDevices(DeviceService.kt:124)
    at maestro.cli.device.DeviceService.listConnectedDevices(DeviceService.kt:114)
    at maestro.cli.device.PickDeviceInteractor.pickDeviceInternal(PickDeviceInteractor.kt:33)
    at maestro.cli.device.PickDeviceInteractor.pickDevice(PickDeviceInteractor.kt:14)
    at maestro.cli.util.MaestroFactory.createMaestro(MaestroFactory.kt:35)
    at maestro.cli.command.TestCommand.call(TestCommand.kt:63)
    at maestro.cli.command.TestCommand.call(TestCommand.kt:31)
    at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:1933)
    at picocli.CommandLine.access$1200(CommandLine.java:145)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2332)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2326)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2291)
    at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2159)
    at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2058)
    at maestro.cli.AppKt.main(App.kt:97)
```

i@is-MacBook-Pro samples % maestro test android-flow.yaml

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you currently have two JDK versions, for Maestro it works fine if you install JDK 11 and delete the other versions and then check